# How can I use logical operations in android data binding?

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

In my layout file I'm trying to use the following syntax to specify the text inside `TextView`:

```
android:text="@{user.isMe() && user.status.isEmpty() ? @string/EmptyStatusHint : user.status}"/>
```

and I'm getting:

> [Fatal Error] fragment_user_profile.xml:142:58: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

In [Data Binding Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#expression_language) there is no something special about.

So, regarding this situatuion, I have two questions:

1. How can I use my logical statement in xml for data binding?
2. What is the "*entity*" mentioned in the error report? I suppose I should know that ))

Comment: &amp;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
"   &quot;
'   &apos;

Comment: use the following for & lesserthan so on hope this is helpful

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must write && as  `&amp;&amp;`   .

Comment: what is the difference between `&&` and `&&`.

Comment: How about `||`?